# How to automatically replace a word with another?

Tags: python, django

I am currently using Django 4.0 and trying to find a way to transform the following: [year] to the current year.

It needs to be automatically replaced every time [year] is found. Be it from the admin panel, from CKEDITOR, or comments, etc.

I can find ways to do this when [year] is hardcoded, but I don't know how to make it work when I am posting a blog post from Django Admin, for example.

To also add, I have tried using JS to transform the [year] tag to the current year. The problem with this is that it doesn't work on the page title or for search engines. They will still index the page with [year] instead of 2022, for example. Using JS works well for people, but not from a SEO perspective.

Comment: Are you able to modify the html files? Why not make a variable in the jinja template and then pass the year as part of the context? So it would be {{ year }} instead of [year]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not using Jinja. I don't know how this would solve the problem when posting and article from Admin Panel for example.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Have you looked into setting up a sql trigger that could transform [year]? The trigger could kick off after every edit/create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple:

Let's suppose we have a model called Post and it has a content field:

```
from datetime import date

current_year = date.today().year

new_post = Post.objects.last()

if "[year]" in new_post.content:
    new_post.content.replace("[year]", str(current_year)  )
```